# SonarQube Cannot Read the lcov.info for JavaScript

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, isparta

I am using karma-coverage together with isparta-loader in my JavaScript unit test to generate the `lcov.info` file.

However, when I run the SonarQube analysis using [JavaScript Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JavaScript+Plugin), the test coverage report is not generated. If the `lcov.info` contains data for 1 file, the coverage report is not failing, but if the `lcov.info` contains data for 2 files or more, then it always fail at:

> 13:43:27.635 INFO  - Store results in database
>       13:43:27.649 DEBUG - Execute org.sonar.batch.phases.GraphPersister
>       13:43:27.714 DEBUG - Execute org.sonar.batch.index.SourcePersister
>       13:43:29.852 DEBUG - Release semaphore on project : org.sonar.api.resources.Project@6b1e6f8b[id=7859,key=func.salesorder
>       NG,qualifier=TRK], with key batch-func.salesorderNG
>       INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>       INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
>       INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>       Total time: 4:14.804s
>       Final Memory: 23M/828M
>       INFO: --------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
>       org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
>               at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
>               at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
>               at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>               at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
>               at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
>               at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
>               at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
>               at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
>               at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
>               at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to save file sources
>               at org.sonar.batch.index.SourcePersister.persist(SourcePersister.java:84)
>               at org.sonar.batch.phases.DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.executePersisters(DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.java:165)
>               at org.sonar.batch.phases.DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.execute(DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.java:133)
>               at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:264)
>               at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
>               at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
>               at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
>               at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
>               at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:220)
>               at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
>               at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
>               at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57)
>               at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45)
>               at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:135)
>               at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
>               at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
>               at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:158)
>               at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
>               at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
>               at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>               at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
>               ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
>               at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(Unknown Source)
>               at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.protobuf.RepeatedFieldBuilder.getBuilder(RepeatedFieldBuilder.java:245)
>               at org.sonar.server.source.db.FileSourceDb$Data$Builder.getLinesBuilder(FileSourceDb.java:2911)
>               at org.sonar.batch.index.SourceDataFactory.applyLineMeasure(SourceDataFactory.java:183)
>               at org.sonar.batch.index.SourceDataFactory.applyLineMeasures(SourceDataFactory.java:117)
>               at org.sonar.batch.index.SourceDataFactory.consolidateData(SourceDataFactory.java:76)
>               at org.sonar.batch.index.SourcePersister.computeData(SourcePersister.java:152)
>               at org.sonar.batch.index.SourcePersister.persist(SourcePersister.java:93)
>               at org.sonar.batch.index.SourcePersister.persist(SourcePersister.java:81)
>               ... 33 more

The `lcov.info` shows the following information:

```
SF:D:\SOC\src\UI\UI.ng\js\general\services\tabStateService.js
FN:3,_interopRequireDefault
FN:11,(anonymous_2)
FN:14,tabStateService
FN:17,moveNext
FNF:4
FNH:4
FNDA:1,_interopRequireDefault
FNDA:1,(anonymous_2)
FNDA:21,tabStateService
FNDA:2,moveNext
DA:0,1
DA:1,1
DA:4,1
DA:5,1
DA:8,1
DA:9,21
DA:10,21
DA:12,2
LF:8
LH:8
BRDA:3,1,0,0
BRDA:3,1,1,1
BRDA:3,2,0,1
BRDA:3,2,1,1
BRF:4
BRH:4
end_of_record
TN:
SF:D:\SOC\src\UI\UI.ng\js\general\services\pagingService.js
FN:5,(anonymous_1)
FN:8,pagingService
FN:14,getPagingParams
FN:20,calculateSkip
FNF:4
FNH:4
FNDA:1,(anonymous_1)
FNDA:23,pagingService
FNDA:11,getPagingParams
FNDA:7,calculateSkip
DA:1,1
DA:3,1
DA:4,1
DA:7,1
DA:9,23
DA:13,1
DA:14,11
DA:15,2
DA:16,9
DA:17,7
DA:18,2
DA:21,1
DA:22,7
LF:13
LH:13
BRDA:15,1,0,2
BRDA:15,1,1,9
BRDA:15,2,0,11
BRDA:15,2,1,9
BRDA:16,3,0,7
BRDA:16,3,1,2
BRDA:16,4,0,9
BRDA:16,4,1,7
BRF:8
BRH:8
end_of_record
```

Comment: Which version of the JavaScript plugin are you using? And which version of SonarQube?

Comment: 2.4 of the javascript plugin

Comment: We using transpiling the es6 code to es5, i guess that is the cause of the file cannot be understand by sonar

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from this line of your `lcov.info`:

```
    DA:0,1
```

That means that line 0 is covered by unit tests.
That makes the analysis fail, because only strictly positive line numbers are expected.

There's a [ticket](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6183) to improve the behavior of SonarQube in such cases.